# Why can't I get an image from the camera album in Android gallery?

Tags: java, android

I can get images from the gallery, but I can't get from the camera album/roll. But I know I got the URI of an image from the camera roll and still it won't show up in my imageview.

Opening the Gallery:

```
if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        imgUri = data.getData();
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            Intent sendpic = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GalleryChoice.class);
            sendpic.putExtra("imagePath", imgUri.toString());
            Log.d("SHOW UP", imgUri.toString());
            startActivity(sendpic);
```

Getting the URI from the previous activity to show up in the ImageView, where the image is not showing up.

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("imagePath")){
        ur = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
        Uri newUri = Uri.parse(ur);
        try {
            bitmapy = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), newUri);
            imgView1.setImageBitmap(bitmapy);
        }
        catch (IOException e){

        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It generally happens when the `Image` is large is size which is `2048*2048`. Generally camera roll captures images larger in size, if the image has any length and width sized more than `2048`, It require cropping.

- Valid size to set on `ImageView < 2048*2048`, from camera roll

**Below is just an example to crop image if large in size,and does not take care of image ratio**

```
    public class InputImageCompressor extends Activity{

    public static void compressInputImage(Uri inputImageData, Context context, ImageView newIV)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        //Uri inputImageData = data.getData();
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmapInputImage = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), inputImageData);
            if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() > 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1920, 1200, true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() > 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, 1024, 1280, true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
            else if (bitmapInputImage.getWidth() < 2048 && bitmapInputImage.getHeight() < 2048)
            {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapInputImage, bitmapInputImage.getWidth(), bitmapInputImage.getHeight(), true);
                newIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Use this in your code:

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("imagePath")){
        ur = getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");
        Uri newUri = Uri.parse(ur);
        try {
            InputImageCompressor.compressInputImage(newUri, your_class_name.this, imgView1);
            }
        catch (IOException e){

        }
  }
```

Why image size limited to 2048*2048 **[read more](https://www.scirra.com/forum/maximum-image-size-of-2048_t126211)**

Answer (score 0):

Check if `Uri` is valid. If it's, use method below to get it's real address.

```
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri){
    String filePath = "";
    String[] filePahColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, filePahColumn, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePahColumn[0]);
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    return filePath;
}
```

Use this `filePath` to set your image

```
yourImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath));
```

You can use this to scale down your image.

Comment: did my answer helped?